# How do I say 'On second thought' in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say *"On second thought"* in Spanish?

> Pensándolo bien, ¡no vamos al cine!

Are there any alternative for this?

Comment: *"al pensarlo mejor"*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression *«pensándolo bien»* is a very good translation and pretty common.  Also *«pensándolo mejor»*.

Some alternatives:

1. *reconsiderándolo*
2. *por otro lado (sería mejor)*
3. *ahora que lo pienso* (suggested by Alexis and SysDragon)
4. *repensándolo* (suggested by Diego Andrés)
5. *si lo pienso (bien/mejor)* (suggested by Diego Andrés)
6. *al pensarlo mejor* (suggested by vartec)

(I'll keep posting if I remember more)

Comment: *Ahora que lo pienso* is also a good candidate.

Answer (score 3):

`Pensándolo bien`, the one that you gave, is the most common in my opinion, but you could also use:

> Pensándolo mejor, ...
>
> Ahora que lo pienso, ...
>
> Mejor pensado, ...

And some sentences that should be used with context, but can have similar meaning:

> Ya que lo dices, ...
>
> Ahora que caigo, ...

Answer (score 0):

There is an informal use which is `dando una vuelta más`, an even more informal `dando una vuelta de tuerca`. Also you can use:

- Si lo pienso mejor
- Ahora que lo pienso mejor
- Ahora que lo pienso bien
- Pensando mejor
- Repensándolo
- Desde otro punto de vista
- Pensando nuevamente

Comment: rebobinando el casete

Comment: [vuelta de tuerca](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuelta_de_tuerca_%28argumento%29) tiene un significado distinto a "pensándolo mejor". Es más bien como "giro sorprendente"